# Windows : How to detect if computer was shut down remotely?

Tags: windows, command-line, shutdown

A computer in domain is randomly shut down by someone (he was caught once)!

He uses `shutdown /s /f /t 0 /m \\computername` in windows command line to accomplish this.

After the incident some computers randomly shut down several times a week, but maybe not by the same person.

Now the question is: Is it possible to detect / monitor if a computer was shut down remotely, and by who? (eg in Event Viewer)

Comment: Maybe you can take a look in System Event log? I think it should contain some details about which process initiated the shutdown.

Comment: @EugeneS - the system log does not contain any info related to shutdowns.

Answer (score 2):

Try filtering the **System** log with the `User32` event source, and `1074` Event ID ([see more](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=1074&EvtSrc=User32&LCID=1033)).

Unless you have enabled the [Shutdown Event Tracker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770960.aspx) the "Other (Unplanned)" reason, is normal.

Comment: we are running Windows XP Pro on all machines, and the article says "This feature is not included in Windows XP Professional."